# Text centered next to image, and if no space, aligned to top

Tags: html, css

Let's check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWMkH/):

```
img {
    float: left;
}

#inner {
    height: 128px; 
    background-color: yellowgreen; 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#content {
    background-color: red;
}

<img src="http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/250x250/37934290.jpg" width="128" height="128" />
<div id="inner">
    <div id="content">text text tertkl elknr tlken lsl kdmfsldkfmsldkfmslkd mfkndfln dflkfndg lkn</div>
</div>
```

this works so far as I expect - text is centered, and as you shrink the width, text goes underline: but then its "too far" from the image. The best would be if the `vertical-align: middle;` became `vertical-align: top;` when it needs to jump. How to do it without possibly jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand the problem - the vertically centred element remains vertically centred even at low widths.

Comment: I believe the OP means when the text wraps to the line below the image, they'd like it to be vertically aligned to the top so it's not so far below the image, but right under it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to achieve this is to use a [CSS Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Your markup would stay the same and your CSS would only need to have the following added:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
    #inner {
        vertical-align: top;   
    }
}
```

<sup>*in action: http://jsfiddle.net/uWMkH/1/*</sup>

What that says is, "When the viewport's width is no more than 290px, do this stuff to `#inner`.

Take a look at these links for more information:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
- http://cssmediaqueries.com/
- http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

The caveat with using media queries to do this is that they aren't supported in IE8 and below. I hope you don't have to deal with those headaches!

Look here for a complete list of browsers with support:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: What doesn't work in Firefox?  There's nothing in this answer that only works in Opera.  Though the media queries would be better written for the wider device:  http://jsfiddle.net/uWMkH/2/

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this without media queries, but it requires a browser that supports the *entire* CSS Flexible box module (most browsers are missing support for wrapping).  At this point in time, support is limited to Opera, Chrome, and IE10.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/rFdkt

```
figure {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  figure {
    display: flex;
  }
}

figcaption {
  -webkit-flex: 1 15em;
  -ms-flex: 1 15em;
  flex: 1 15em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

What Flexbox offers over media queries is the ability to reflow the content based on the available space, not just the browser width.